# Elasticsearch Analyzer Inheritance

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have an analyzer as below.

```
                "custom_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "char_filter": [
                        "html_strip"
                    ],
                    "filter": [
                        "stemming_exclusion",
                        "kstem"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "standard"
                }
```

Now I want to have another custom analyzer with just one additional filter. Something like this:

```
                "custom_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "char_filter": [
                        "html_strip"
                    ],
                    "filter": [
                        "stemming_exclusion",
                        "kstem",
                        "new_filter"

                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "standard"
                }
```

Is there a way to reuse previous *custom_analyzer* instead of copying everything again? This example is a shortened one but assume I have many filters, char_filters etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's currently no way to do it in ES.

You can reuse character filters, token filters and tokenizers, which is already quite a good thing, but you have to fully declare each analyzer you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!